# Any way to get as an array all the values that has a field?

Tags: propel

I mean, after after a doSelect(), I get an array of objects, and I'm interested in getting just the values of a field. I'm interested also in storing the values in an array.

I know i could use a foreach and getField() functions, but I'm wondering if there is something like "array getFieldValues()".

Regards

Sf 1.4/Propel 1.6

Javi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want one field of all objects, [you can use the `select()` method of the `Query` class](http://www.propelorm.org/wiki/Documentation/1.5/ModelCriteria#GettingColumnsInsteadOfObjects):

```
// When you need only one column, use a column name as the select() argument
$articles = ArticleQuery::create()
  ->join('Category')
  ->select('Title')
  ->find();
// returns array('foo', 'bar')
```

Comment: thanks, but you just forget to add "->toArray()" in the query!